# Centering the widgets within a StackLayout in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to center the widgets within a StackLayout horizontally, but I'm both a newb and not very good at math, and can't wrap my head around the correct formula.  Each widget within the StackLayout is 128 pixels wide, and the spacing between each widget is 20 pixels.  Here's what I have:

```
padding: ((root.width - ((int((root.width - ((int(root.width / 128) - 1) * 20)) / 128) - 1) * 20)) % 128) / 2, 0, 0, 0
spacing: 20
```

It works well to a point.  For instance, when the window width is any amount up to 255 pixels, it centers a single 128 pixel widget perfectly per row.  But once the window is resized to 256 pixels wide, each widget is then positioned hard left with a padding of 0.  As I increase the width of the window from 256 to 275, padding will increase in turn.  At 276 pixels wide the widgets snap back to the hard left position with a padding of 0, and a 2nd widget is then placed on each row (which is good and how it should work).

Plugging a value into the formula, I can see why this happens, but I'm just not sure how to fix it.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is easier to achieve with a `GridLayout`. It will look like this for **different size buttons and spacing of 20**:

[image]

The trick is to put two dummy widgets to fill the spaces on the sides (*since default size_hint is 1,1*):

---

#### Code Example

You would need to run the below example with the size parameter to control the size of the window (alternatively you can use the mouse to shrink it):

```
python gridlayout.py --size=500x30
```

And you need two files. First, the `gridlayout.kv`:

```
<GridLayout>:
    rows: 1
    spacing: 20

    Widget:
    Button:
        text: 'A'
        size_hint: None, 1
        width: 25
    Button:
        text: 'B'
        size_hint: None, 1
        width: 50
    Button:
        text: 'C'
        size_hint: None, 1
        width: 25
    Widget:
```

And second, the python code `gridlayout.py`:

```
import kivy

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

class GridLayoutApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return GridLayout()

if __name__=="__main__":
    GridLayoutApp().run()
```